How to assign a type based on the existance of a property?
I'm trying to apply a type if the object has x. What I tried had unexpected results. Can anyone explain the results and/or offer a solution?
interface BaseType {
  x?: number;
  a?: string;
  b?: number;
}

interface WithoutX extends Omit<BaseType, "x"> {
  
};

interface WithX extends Omit<BaseType, "x"> {
  x: any;
  y: string;
};

type ConditionalType = WithX | WithoutX;

// No `x` or `y`, conforms to WithoutX
const validObject1: ConditionalType = {
  a: "hello",
  b: 42
};

// Has `x` and `y`, conforms to WithX
const validObject2: ConditionalType = {
  a: "world",
  x: 10,
  y: "required"
};

// This should cause a type error because `y` is required if `x` is present
const shouldBeInvalidButIsNot: ConditionalType = {
  a: "typescript",
  x: 10
};

const invalidObjectBecauseX: WithoutX = {
  a: "typescript",
  x: 10
};

const invalidObjectBecauseYMissing: WithX = {
  a: "typescript",
  x: 10
};

Playground

TypeScript object types are not "sealed"; the mere absence of x as a property in a type doesn't preclude properties of that name from existing (else you could never extend interfaces by adding properties). If you want to say "no x" you can give it an optional x property of type never, which gets you most of the way there, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

That does provide me with a solution for my current situation. Please feel free to write it up as an answer and I will mark it as correct.
Of course it limits the combinations of types you can have because the others have to fall back to the x: never type to work. It's not quite the same as saying if it has x then it must also have y. But it solved my problem. Thanks.
